# Angular: Best way to pass data between components?

Tags: angular, web-services, typescript, command-line-interface

I have an interface in root (app folder) **mydata.ts**

```
export interface mydata{
   Data1: string;
   Data2: string[];
}
```

which have my **app.component.ts** as

```
import { Component , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from "./api.service"
import { mydata } from "./mydata";
import { error } from 'util';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    providers:[ApiService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  title = 'app';

  _dataArray: mydata[];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService){}

  getData(): void {
    this.apiService.getData().
    subscribe(
       resultArray => this._dataArray =
       resultArray,
       error => console.log("Error :: " + error ))
  }
  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.getData();

  }
}
```

which get the data from my API service in root folder **api-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response} from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import {mydata} from "./mydata";
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {



  constructor(private http: Http ) {}
 getData(): Observable<mydata[]>{
   //For WebService
  return this.http
  .get('../assets/testdata.json').pipe(
    map(response => {
      return <mydata[]>response.json();
    }),catchError(this.handleError));

  }


 private handleError(error: Response) {
   return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
 }

}
```

I have child components that I want to use that data as well what is the best method to share data when I have more than one component that will be using it.

Here's the content of my app.component.html

```
<app-databody></app-databody> //child component
<app-datafilters></app-datafilters> //child component
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: If the immediate children components need the data from their parent, `@Input` should be able to help you achieve what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An way is to use Dependency Injection, you can use it on Module level or component level by declaring a data-service in the providers-section.

For example, in a component it would look like this

```
@Component({
providers: [AService] // < - provided,
  template : `<todos></todos>`
})

export class AComponent {
  constructor(private aservice: AService) {}
}
```

If you do it like this, you can also use this service in all child components of this component.

In a module, this is about the same, but there the service becomes visible in all declared components for that module.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want to use it like a singleton service for the whole app or component level service you can declare either in the providers[servicename] in the module or you can declare it the same way in your component

Just create a common service for all the component and if you want to share data between the two you can declare it on the module level for accessing the same data or if you want the a new service instance for each component you can declare it on the component level

From your code you are declaring the service on module level so if you import that service in your components and try to use it inside them they will return the same data as it is a singleton service